# How to get filtered values from MUI datagrid

Tags: javascript, material-ui, datagrid

Is it possible to get values from mui DataGrid?

I have a table and i want to have a custom export based on user filter and columns that are hidden or displayed but i need these filtered values. There is any way to get this from DataGrid?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use the [`gridFilteredSortedRowIdsSelector`](https://mui.com/components/data-grid/filtering/#selectors)
Most of the useful seletors for exporting are defined in the ["Exported rows" section](https://mui.com/components/data-grid/export/#exported-rows)

Answer (score 0):

The prop onSelectionModelChange gives you the IDs of the selected cells, and then you can filter them based on your requirements to export the selected ones.

```
 <DataGridPro
  onSelectionModelChange={(props)=>{
            console.log(props);
          }}
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

DataGrid MUI has `onStateChange`, which have all the values, filtered values, count, and current state of the grid:

```js
onStateChange={(e) => {
  console.log(e.pagination.rowCount)
  console.log(e)
}}
```